# SharePoint online column update

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, powerapp

I have a SP list, one of the columns contains different numbers. I need to replace these numbers with text.

For instance, if column color contains:

1 -> replace it with the text white

2 -> replace it with the text black

And so on, is there a simple PowerApp that can be manually triggered to do that?

I tried using the following JSON for the column:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=if(@currentField == 1, 'white', if(@currentField == 2, 'Black', ''))"
}
```

but when filtering the column, it will show the numbers 1,2,etc instead of the text (white, black, etc..).

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior in SharePoint while using JSON Formatting as JSON formatting only customizes the "display" of the list column and does not store/modify the actual value of column.

So while filtering on column you will see the actual values instead of JSON formatted values.

---

For your requirements, you can use calculated columns in SharePoint.

Use below formula in calculated column:

```
=IF([Column1] = 1, "White", IF([Column1] = 2, "Black", ""))
```

Where [Column1] is the name of your number column.

Comment: The column is Text single line. I tried running a flow using: replace(outputs('ComposeTitle'),'1','white') - but could not figure out how to modify replace so it check for other options, like replace(outputs('ComposeTitle'),'1','white'), replace(outputs('ComposeTitle'),'2','black') etc...

Comment: If column is single line text, you can use formula like: `=IF(Value([Column1]) = 1, "White", IF(Value([Column1]) = 2, "Black", ""))`

Comment: Thanks Ganesh, do I need to add it under Column Formatting in SP list?

Comment: No, create a new column with "Calculated" as data/column type and use above formula for calculation. Replace *Column1* with actual name of your number column.

Comment: Hi @Sarmad, does this answers your question? If yes, please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.