# Replace semicolon with comma in SharePoint text colomn

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I am having an issue replacing the semicolon with a comma. I am using the JSON replaceall function to do this, and it looks like it does the job. However, you can still see the semicolon when you export to Excel or edit in grid view.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=replaceAll(@currentField, ';', ',')"
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior in SharePoint while using JSON Formatting as SharePoint JSON formatting only customizes the **display** of the list columns and does not store/modify the actual value of column.

So while [exporting the list to excel file](https://support.microsoft.com/office/export-to-excel-from-sharepoint-or-lists-bfb2ea48-6118-4fa9-abb6-cced9424e5d9?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224) or while [editing data in grid view](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2024/01/27/disable-quick-property-editing-grid-view-from-sharepoint-online-list/), in column you will see the actual values instead of JSON formatted values.

**Similar thread**: [SharePoint online column update](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/302503/sharepoint-online-column-update/302504#302504)

**Documentation**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224):

> *You can use column formatting to customize how fields in SharePoint lists and libraries are displayed. To do this, you construct a JSON object that describes the elements that are displayed when a field is included in a list view, and the styles to be applied to those elements. The column formatting **does not** change the data in the list item or file; it only changes how it’s displayed to users who browse the list.*

---

**Update from comments**:

For bulk update list items, you can either use PowerShell or Power Automate.

Check the solution given here for detailed Power automate flow: [Ways to replace semicolon with comma or remove the semicolon](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/312711/ways-to-replace-semicolon-with-comma-or-remove-the-semicolon)

[image]

Comment: so if we want to modify the semicolon and replace it with comma, can we do this with powershell?

Comment: Yes, you can do one time update using PowerShell. How many items are there in the list? Are these items added by users manually or programmatically?

Comment: all manually. there are few lists, from 100 items to 20000 items

Comment: I guess, you can use PowerShell for this.