Ways to replace semicolon with comma or remove the semicolon
I have 10 document libraries with different numbers of records, from 500 to 20000.
Under the Invoice Tracking Text column, users used a semicolon to separate entries; however, for some reason, I needed to remove the semicolon and replace it with a comma or space.
I have used JSON script; however, JSON's script changes the display name, and I need to change the character from a semicolon to either a comma or remove it.


Try using flow like this:

Expression used in "Compose" action:
replace(item()?['TextColumn'],';',',')

Where TextColumn is an internal name of your column in SharePoint list. You can get the internal name of your SharePoint list columns by following this article: How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?

You will have to set Pagination in settings of "Get items" action as per the total list items you have in the SharePoint list.
Check:

Enter a constant item in a column
Get Items returns no data


Update from comments:
Here are all high level actions in the flow for manually triggered flow:


Note: I have cropped few options/properties of "Get items" action in above attached screenshot which were not required to show for this requirement.

I will try it today and I will get back to you.

I had to change the expression a little bit to make it work. My next question is how to apply the solution to all the existing records.
replace (triggerOutputs()? ['body/TrackingNumber'] , ' ; ' , ' , ' )

Yes, you have to change the expression as per your column names. Use manually triggered flow for updating all existing items in the list and run that flow manually one time. Manual trigger --> Get items action --> all other actions as shown in above image.

by Manual Trigger option you mean when you create a flow, you select Instant cloud flow?

Yes, first select Instant cloud flow and then on pop up, select "Manually trigger a flow". After saving the flow, you can manually run/test it using "Test" option at the top like: https://i.sstatic.net/XyLWI.png

Is it working fine for you now?
